# Determine the density of this problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with a common density. You know this density has support only within the interval $[a, b]$ and that it is symmetric around $(a + b)/2$ (but you are not told anything more about the density). In addition, you are told that the sum $Z = X + Y$ has density $g^+ (t)$ (which is given to you). How can you determine the density $g^− (t)$ of the variable $W = X − Y$ given this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the convolution of density functions is the density of the sum:
$$g^+ = f \ast f$$
Depending on the given $g^+$ and knowing about the symmetry and support of $f$ you can try to solve the equation

$$g^+(s) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) f(s-t) \ \mathrm dt = (f \ast f)(s)$$